# Access passcode locked iPhone with broken screen without jailbreaking

Tags: iphone, ios, password

My iPhone screen broke but I know my passcode.

**Is there anyway I can enter my passcode from my Mac? If yes, what app/software?**

1. I already deleted my backup (iCloud) due to space, so I need to back it up before I wipe it. Can someone guide me through the process or a share a viable link? Apple Support Communities is too ambiguous for me.
2. This image seems relevant:

   [image]

My screen is not functioning. 
I've tried iExplorer/iBrowser, all to no avail.
I need an app/software to control my iPhone from my Mac.

Comment: Image in the link is for another purpose.

Comment: my iPhone screen broke but i know my passcode.
Is there an app/software I can use to enter my passcode from my mac?

Comment: AFAIK, There isn't any way you can do that from a Mac.

Comment: @Jash Jacob, do you know any way around it?

Comment: I've voted to reopen this, as I think the question is clear enough - though I still think the answer will be "you're right out of luck"

Comment: @Tetsujin See the answer given here and the linked duplicate, there are ways!

Comment: @grgarside - Thanks George, I wasn't actually sure there was a solution.... but I'll stick with my comprehensive backup strategy until such time as it remains the *only* solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1: USB keyboard

You can use the [Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD821AM/A/lightning-to-usb-camera-adapter).

1. Connect the adapter to your iPhone.
2. Connect a USB keyboard to the adapter.
3. Enter your passcode

---

### Solution 2: Bluetooth keyboard

If you had connected a bluetooth keyboard to your iPhone before you can use it to enter your iPhone's passcode.

1. Make sure your iPhone has bluetooth enabled
2. Turn on your keyboard and pair wait for it to connect to your iPhone.
3. Enter your unlock passcode.