# How can i remotely type my passcode while iphone is plugged to my mac

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, password, data-recovery

I want to backup my iphone 5s but the screen is entirely broken, it's all black and the touchscreen + home button do not work.
I need to control my phone from a keyboard to back it up from icloud on my mac that recognises it.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284027/access-passcode-locked-iphone-with-broken-screen-without-jailbreaking?rq=1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128547/control-and-see-iphone-from-mac-with-broken-iphone-screen. With the increased security measures included in recent iOS version the solutions described there might not work any longer though

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running?

Comment: I'm not sure 100% but it is fairly recent

Answer (score 2):

**Definitely not possible**
no access over computer keyboard if your device has not been jailbroken
*with openssh preinstalled before*

**You can use iCloud Backup** on recognized WIFI networks to sync automatically
*if previously enabled, though*

> If your iPhone gets recognized by iTunes on your Mac, you are still good to go for a screen replacement considering it not being as expensive as a data loss, nor the lightning keyboard **and more important** you don't lose your app tokens, for example some **banking apps**, app-related **logins**, **authenticator apps**, etc.